# Get the title of a page using a URL from within a Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How do I get a website title (anything in between the title tags) using only the URL (without the tab). I am attempting this: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html but am unsure of the implementation/if it can even work.

Here's what I have:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", info.linkUrl, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
    alert((/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(data)[1]);
    callback(data);
}
xhr.send();
```

My permissions are set, but nothing is happening.

---

edit: now how do I return it? here is my attempt:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.open("GET", info.linkUrl, true);
 xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        var title = (/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(xhr.responseText)[1];
        results.push({
            title: title
        });
        //callback(title);
    }
    xhr.processed = true;
    xhr.abort();
 }
 try {
    xhr.send();
 } catch(e) {
    //do something
 }
```

what now?

Comment: what does chromes developer tool says? Which errors occure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you use the XMLHTTPRequest object is wrong. The code below should work.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", info.linkUrl, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var title = (/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(xhr.responseText)[1];
    alert(title); 
  }
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. Now I am trying to return the title, how do I go about doing that? Sorry, I am new to these kind of requests

Comment: I figured it out (use a callback!). But for some reason nothing works for google search results (any ideas on why/how to fix)? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: If I run `(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/m).exec(document.documentElement.innerHTML)` in the JavaScript console while viewing a google search results page then it returns the title as expected. Can you give more details about the issue you're facing?

Comment: For me at least, Google is doing some sort of javascript redirect. I got around it though using a special case and string parsing. Thanks for all your help.